# Correlation coefficient to use for data with non linear relationship

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, scipy, association-measure

I am working with the following y = x^2 data type for my test studies

```
from scipy import stats
x1 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
x2 = [4, 1, 0, 1, 4]
tau, p_value = stats.kendalltau(x1, x2)
spearmanCorr = stats.spearmanr(x1, x2)[0]
```

tau is 0
spearmanCorr is 0

What is the best correlation coefficient to use for data of this kind ?

Edit: Based on comments below, then is there a metrics to measure the relationship at all ?

Comment: This depends on what you want to measure. Different correlations measure (slightly) different things. "Correlation" normally refers to the concept that variables have an overall positive or negative relationship - for y=x^2 the relationship is negative below x=0 and positive above. These cancel each other out for data symmetric about 0, so there's nothing wrong with a value of 0. If this is not what you want, you want something other than what is normally referred to as "correlation".

Comment: None of the above. Pearson, Spearman, and Kendall measure monotonic relationships, yours is not monotonic.

Comment: I’m with @Lewian. You’re looking for something other than correlation. Perhaps you want mutual information, though mutual information is far from a generalization of correlation.

Comment: @Dave yes mutual information is the correct term here. Can you please help me explore any such related algorithms i.e. give me some keywords to google?

Comment: “Mutual information” is a technical term in information theory, not just the gist of what you want to know, so it is its own keyword.